# MSMQ .Net 2.0 Peek vs Receive

Tags: c#, vb.net, exception, msmq, peek

MSMQ is set up on server running Windows 2003 R2 SP 2.  .Net 2.0 is installed.  All messages being sent to this queue are supposed to be of type QMsg.  Regardless, Peek returns an object of type System.Messaging.Message BUT the Body is erroring with an exception that indicates the Root is missing. I have set the breakpoint at the 'This' definition and can peer into the 'Something' instance.

> Body = {"Cannot deserialize the message passed as an argument. Cannot
>   recognize the serialization format."}

```
public QMsg GetCommand()
{
    Message Something = mqCompany.Peek();
    string This = Something.Body.GetType.ToString.ToLower;
    //. . . Code to check the type of Body
    return (QMsg)mqCompany.Receive().Body;
}

Private Function GetCommand() as QMsg
    Dim Something as Message = mqCompany.Peek()
    Dim This as string = Something.Body.GetType.ToString.ToLower
    . . . Code to check the type of Body
    GetCommand = CType(mqCompany.Receive().Body, QMsg)
End Function
```

If I allow the 'This' statement to execute, it throws the exception.  However, if I skip to the final statement, which contains the Receive method, it executes just fine.  The strangest thing is that once the Receive is executed once, the Peek will work on everything after that.  Is there something special I need to do before executing Peek initially?

Comment: This cannot be your actual code, or else you're missing something (like freaky extension methods). For starters, `Something.Body` cannot compile because `Something` is of type `object`, which has no `Body` member.

Comment: You are correct.  I was trying to reduce the code down and missed that.  I will fix it now.

Comment: So you have one message with a fekkedup body.  Probably best to look at the other end of the wire for the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks but is there any way I can tell in my code if **Body** is invalid?

Comment: Of course, you get an exception.  If that happens on the Peek() then you'll be reminded about it more than once, can't miss it.  If you prefer the ignore-something-really-bad-happened approach, then I doubt we can help you.

Comment: @HansPassant I know that.  Why would you assume I was wanting to ignore something really bad?  Are you recommending that I let the exception occur and code for an error?  I was just asking if there was a way to tell in advance of the code that causes the exception.  Peek doesn't return any indications of a problem as far as I can tell.  The resulting Message object is not null/nothing.  What other clues are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read from `Message.Body` property, .Net will try to deserialize it and create object. By default, object deserialization is performed using `XMLMessageFormatter`. That message you got suggests that body was originaly serialized some other way, perhaps using `BinaryMessageFormatter` or not sent from .Net at all.

In order to solve this, you must take a look at sending side, check which formatter is used there and configure it same for receiving. Also, if `XMLMessageFormatter` is used, you must set its `TargetTypes` or `TargetTypeNames` property when receiving.

It's also possible that message is not .Net serialized object at all. In that case, you can use `BodyStream` property to directly access body byte by byte and decode it any way you have to.

For this issue it's entirely irrelevant whether you use Peek or Receive. Messages body will be handled same way.